# Oracle function to drop table if exists

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following bit of code:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    INTO table1_exists
    FROM
        sys.all_tables
    WHERE
        table1_name = upper('table1');

EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        table1_exists := 0;
END;

IF ( table1_exists ) = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[Drop Table table1]';
END IF;
```

How could I create a SQL function to, given a table name as an input, drop if exists that table?

Comment: This procedure may fail if `TABLE1` exists in another schema. Better use `USER_TABLES` or include `OWNER` in your query.

Comment: By default table names are upper case. But it is possible to have a table `table1` and `TABLE1` - though rather uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to drop it and suppress "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error:

```sql
declare
  e_not_exists exception;
  pragma exception_init(e_not_exists, -942);
begin
  execute immediate 'drop table blabla';
exception 
  when e_not_exists then null;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting the full procedure, following Sayan Malakshinov's answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE drop_ifne (
    table_name IN VARCHAR2
) IS
    e_not_exists EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init ( e_not_exists, -942 );
    vstr CLOB;
BEGIN
    vstr := q'[drop table ]' || table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( vstr );
EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_not_exists THEN
        NULL;
END;
```